# Replacing a value within a string JS

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a string with 4 values called alpha1 "abcd" and another string with 4 values called alpha2 "abce". I want to create a function that translates a given alpha1 string into alpha2 such that:
function "abcd" returns "abce"
function "dddd" returns "eeee"
function "bbdd" returns "bbee"
Here's my attempt:

```
function Replace() {
Replace.replace("d", "e");
}
```

Comment: So you want a function that replaces instances of "d" in a string with "e"s?

Comment: any where would expect Replace class come from in your code? :D have you tried googling 'string replace javascript'? a hint is that first link has all the info

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @Andy, exactly, a function that replaces instances of "d" in a string with "e"s.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you `return` the changed string. The `g` tells the `replace` method to replace globally.

```
function replacer(str) {
  return str.replace('d', 'e', 'g');
}

replacer('abcd'); // abce
```

You can also use a regex to get the same result:

```
function replacer(str) {
  return str.replace(/d/g, 'e');
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dz8ap8gd/)

Comment: thanks! unfortunately, this still doesn't pass the 'function "dddd" returns "eeee"' test, it returns "eddd" instead. Any ideas?